# C++ Best Practice: function to accept uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, float

Tags: c++

i've got a set of (potential overloading) functions:

```
write(uint16_t index, uint16_t subindex, uint8_t  data)
write(uint16_t index, uint16_t subindex, uint16_t data)
write(uint16_t index, uint16_t subindex, uint32_t data)
write(uint16_t index, uint16_t subindex, float    data)
```

Despite eclipse showing me for example `typedef unsigned short int  uint16_t;` when I hover over the `uint16_t`, I've got the error:

```
call of overloaded ‘`write(int, int, int)`’ is ambiguous
```

Inside the function I must know, if data was a `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, etc.

What can i do?
Is there another way, e.g. 
    `write(uint16_t index, uint16_t subindex, int data, enum type)` ?

Comment: how do you call your `write` functions?

Comment: there are many `write()` functions in C++. make sure you call the "right one" - your code.

Comment: `int` is not `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` nor `float`. Which one do you expect to call ?

Comment: BTW - this is not specific to unintX_t, you can [get exactly the same behavior with](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l0jKDaZqP5fR8w9n), for example, `unsigned short` and `unsigned int`

Comment: Why not using a function template?

Comment: I thought about a function template, too. But i haven't used one yet. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call is ambiguous because the compiler doesn't know which version of the function you want to call. For example, usage like this:

```
write(1, 2, 3);
```

What is the `3`? It could be `uint8_t` or `uint16_t` or the others ...

Instead of guessing, and potentially doing some crazy things, the compiler tells you it can't know. You can solve this in several ways:

1. Define distinct names for your functions eg. `writeUInt8t(... , uint8_t in)`
2. Specify exactly which to call in your use of the function: `write(1, 2, static_cast<uint8_t>(3))`

Comment: BTW, where can I see `uint*_t` in the standard? can't seem to see it in [basic.types](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.types#basic.fundamental)

Comment: @codekaizer Not sure where in the standard, but they are part of the types system introduced in c++11. Before that they where usually in `cstdint` so probably platform dependant. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. last question, are there no rules of integral promotion or integral conversion for `int*_t` types?

Comment: @codekaizer the `cstdint` types are all aliases of basic types, but which specific type is implementation defined

Comment: I think even if the compiler knew that 3 was int16_t, it would still be ambiguous as it is has to do an implicit conversion to an unsigned type and it doesn't know which unsigned type to convert to.

Comment: @ChrisDrew You are right, it was a typo because i didnt read the question carefully enough. Fixed.